# Bash: passing file pattern as an argument to a command through a variable

Tags: bash, find

My apologies if this is already answered, but if it is I can't find the proper search terms.

I'm trying to dynamically define search terms (based on user defined settings) for the find command:

```
# reading user settings results in array of filename patterns to delete:
patterns=("*.url" "*.html")
for i in ${patterns[@]}; do 
  find . -iname $i -delete
done
```

If I `echo` the command, the resulting string looks correct, e.g.

```
find . -iname "*.url" -delete
find . -iname "*.html" -delete
```

I know I'm missing something obvious but nothing I've tried works.

I'm using Bash 4.4.5 if that helps.

----------------EDIT-----------------

My thanks to Charles Duffy and l'L'l for the correct solution(s). I had a hard time wrapping my head around the quotes in the array strings vs the quoted variables and failed to quote both variables at the same time.

Lesson learned: always quote shell variables.

Comment: This is a problem that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch for you.

Comment: I'm not going to answer my own question yet (in case someone has a better solution or explanation), but I have found a solution. It appears the double quotes in the array are the issue. If I strip the quotes in the array and soft quote the var `"$i"`, it works as expected. There is subtle difference between a string that includes quotes and a quoted string that I'm not grokking yet.

Comment: Removing the quotes from the array definition is wrong -- it causes the glob to be expanded at assignment time, rather than evaluated by `find`.

Comment: Thus, if you had `patterns=( *.html )`, and you had a file `foo.html` in the current directory, you would be running `find . -name foo.html`, not `find . -name "*.html"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the tip. I can see how that site would be helpful in the future but it didn't  resolve the original issue for me, i.e. the suggested quoting of the variables I had already tried without success.

Comment: If it guides you to the correct quoting, then you can focus on other bug sources since you've fixed that one.

Comment: Waitaminute. You're saying that **echo** shows the syntactic quotes?

Comment: It shouldn't -- absolutely, positively shouldn't. `echo "*.url"` doesn't print `"*.url"`, after all, it just prints `*.url`. (This is one of many reasons using `echo` to determine what a script or command will do when run is an antipattern).

Comment: ...the fact that you say `echo find . -iname $i -delete` prints `find . -iname "*.url" -delete` indicates that your actual code doesn't match up with the code in your question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Again thanks. I had left the quotes off thinking that the quotes in the array were sufficient, but I did try it both ways without success. After removing the quotes form the array strings, would quoting the resulting var prevent globbing? I tested with different filenames with the search file extensions in different subdirectories and it appears to work as desired. I'll edit the original question to show my proposed solution as comments are difficult to show formatted code.

Comment: Please add your proposed answer *as an answer*, rather than as an edit to the question. By contrast, if you have a reproducer that lets folks demonstrate the existing/initial problem themselves, by all means do edit it in.

Comment: ...to answer your question: If you've removed the quotes from the assignment in the array, then behavior depends *on the files in the current directory when that assignment takes place*. If you have any `.url` or `.html` files in the current working directory, then the glob will be expanded *at assignment time*, and your array will contain the names of those files, not the pattern.

Comment: (well, depends on the files in the current directory, *and* on the shell options `nullglob` and `failglob`; the above explanation assumes that neither of them is enabled; by contrast, if you quote in every relevant location, none of these options have an effect on your script's behavior).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Lesson learned regarding using echo as a debug tool. Thanks. I suspect I mis-remembered the results when I tried echo as I don't get the quotes now.

Comment: Consider using `set -x` to print your commands as they're run in a more unambiguous form.

Comment: Continuing the explanation: *Either* `${patterns[@]}` or `$i` unquoted will similarly expand a glob if any matches exist in the current directory -- so it's not sufficient to quote any subset if you want to ensure that the literal patterns will be passed all the way through to `find` -- it *must* be all three.

Comment: Again -- proposed answers don't belong in questions (and this one has bugs, as aforementioned -- try running it after `touch foo.url` in the directory where you run your script, and it'll no longer find a `.url` file in a subdirectory with any other name). See ie. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The answer by l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42215725/14122) is a good one, but let's make it a little more efficient, by invoking `find` only once with all your patterns passed in a single command line:

```
patterns=("*.url" "*.html")
find_pat=( )

for i in "${patterns[@]}"; do
  find_pat+=( -o -name "$i" )
done

find . -iname '(' "${find_pat[@]:1}" ')' -delete
```

---

When run, this will invoke:

```
find . -iname '(' -name '*.url' -o -name '*.html' ')' -delete
```

...thus deleting all files which match *either* `*.url` or `*.html` in a single pass.

---

Note:

- We're quoting our globs *at all times*: They're quoted on assignment (so we assign the globs themselves to the `patterns` array), on array expansion (so we iterate over the globs themselves and not their results), and on expansion into the `find` command (so we pass `find` the literal pattern syntax, not the result of expanding that syntax).
- We're prepending `-o` to the `find_pat` array, but then expanding from the second element (arrays being 0-indexed), thus skipping that initial `-o`. The syntax used here is [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: Thanks for all the input and for continuing to educate me to the right solution.  I had planned on building the concatenated pattern after I got the basic form working, I just really had a hard time wrapping my head around the quoted array string vs the quoted variable. That and chasing my tail trying various permutations to "solve" the  problem. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Glad to help. The execution model is tricky, and important to understand -- to give you a very high-level overview that should give you some keywords to search on, unquoted expansions undergo string-splitting and globbing (but *not* other parsing stages such as quote removal, so you can't safely just run `$cmd` to run an arbitrary command stored in that variable -- see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) on that point). You might start with [BashParser](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) and its various links.

Answer (score 3):

You need to double-quote your variables:

```
for i in "${patterns[@]}"; do 
    find . -iname "$i" -delete
...
```

This will prevent globbing and word splitting.

You can always check your script at https://www.shellcheck.net/ for errors as well...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I indeed did fail to quote both the array and loop variable at the same time in my previous testing.  Which [ https://www.shellcheck.net/ ]( https://www.shellcheck.net/ ) did point out.